# grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/ During Installation

Tags: release-hera, system-installation, grub, uefi

New Elementary OS Hera (latest stable release as of yesterday) user here but not new to Linux.

Every time I attempt to install Elementary OS from having the ISO written to a Live boot USB, I get the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/ error on my mid-2012 MacBook Pro.

I built the Live boot USB using unetbooti I think is the name of it.

- I've tried installing by deleting all partitions and letting the installer do that work.
- I've tried manually partitioning by creating an EFI partition of 500MB, a 4GB swap partition and a remaining / partition.
- I've tried installING without an internet connection.

Installing with an internet connection isn't possible. The Mac boot screen allows me to select a wireless connection but it doesn't stay connected once the Elementary OS installer begins. And I don't have the possibility of a wired connection.

I can't install from the Live View because of some other error. Can't remember it at this time. But the Live View doesn't allow me to set up a wireless connection anyway.

I've spent countless hours on this and have read many solutions that worked for others but not for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried with internet too, but still it gives me that error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a way to install successfully without internet. But I enjoy Elementary OS so much that I found a workaround. Hint: you're going to need internet.

I had another PC with both wireless and ethernet capabilities. I shared its wireless connection via its ethernet port to the laptop I wanted to install Elementary OS on. Ran the installer and it completed successfully.